# How to return values from INSERT other that the row that was inserted

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a large number of rows that i want to insert simultaneously into a PostgreSQL database. I need to track what id is assigned for each row that is inserted. For example say we have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
  id serial,
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT example_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

Now i have some data with ids that i dont want inserted (as the serial id column will assign a new id), but i need to keep track of the mapping between the old id and new id:

```
old id | name
-------------
-1     | foo
-2     | bar
-3     | baz
```

So i wrote this query

```
WITH data(oldid,name) AS ( VALUES
    (-1,'foo'),
    (-2,'bar'),
    (-3,'baz')
)
INSERT INTO example(name)
SELECT name FROM data d
RETURNING id, d.oldid
```

Expecting to get something back like:

```
id  | oldid
-----------
1   | -1
2   | -2
3   | -3
```

However this doesn't work, as i don't believe you can return a column that wasn't inserted. Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: The simplest way in my opinion is to add the `oldid` column to your `example` table

Comment: I think `RETURNING` works with row that insert creates - so I cant reference a column from other set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a function that wrapped the inserting of a single row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_example(
    in_name text)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 new_id integer;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO example(name)
    VALUES (in_name) RETURNING id INTO new_id;
    RETURN new_id;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then i can do:

```
WITH data(oldid, name) AS (VALUES
    (-1,'foo'),
    (-2,'bar'),
    (-3,'baz')
)
SELECT oldid, add_example(name) AS id
FROM data
```

Which returns what i expect. I'd like to see if this can be done without the function though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE data_id_seq;

 CREATE TABLE DATA (
      id integer default nextval('data_id_seq') NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      oldid integer,
      name text,
 );

 INSERT INTO DATA(oldid,name) values (-1,'foo'),(-2,'bar'),(-3,'baz') returning id,oldid;
```

Comment: The table that i'm inserting into doesn't have the `oldid` column, is it possible to do without altering the table?

Comment: When you insert values you create a new row. if you want to get the old value you need to use update statement or a combination of update and select

Answer (score 0):

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return
>   value(s) based on each row actually inserted

from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

so column parasite is unavoidable for such solution:

```
alter table example add column old bigint;

WITH d(oldid,name) AS ( VALUES
    (-1,'foo'),
    (-2,'bar'),
    (-3,'baz')
)
INSERT INTO example(name,old)
SELECT "name", oldid FROM d
RETURNING id, old
```